# Set the default thread uncaught exception handler provider in Glassfish

Tags: java, exception, glassfish, uncaughtexceptionhandler

I know how to set the handler in the VM. But I don't know how to set it for a Glassfish environment.

How to set the default thread uncaught exception handler provider in Glassfish?